# How to create custom text format style and apply to hotkey in Pages?

Tags: keyboard, pages, formatting

There are paragraph styles that you can create and tie to the function keys. 
This is all great and dandy, but not if I wish to switch style in the middle of a paragraph and then revert to the one I used to begin with. The whole paragraph will change to the one I just selected.

Is there a way to do what I want, or do I have to manually apply the same font, size and colour every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that there's a thing called "Character Styles" as well that allows me to do exactly what I want!

I created a new style based on a selection and tied it to the function key that I wish to use. 
Perfect.